# CAPTCHA page is puzzling

Tags: bug, design

This is what appears when you hit a CAPTCHA page.

[image: CAPTCHA]

(OK there's some blurb on the right too :-) - it's confusing though!)

Comment: Oh, *that's* where Mechanical Darwin went.

Comment: Do we need a title - "are you human, robot or other...?"

Comment: It says Human Verification on the top of the page like all other SE captcha pages. btw you can reach the captcha page at site.stackexchange/captcha